# branch of logarithms on a simply connected domain

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D =\mathbb{C}\setminus \{e^{(1+i)t}: t ∈ [0, ∞)\}$. This is a simply connected domain. Suppose ℓ is a branch of
logarithm on D, such that $ℓ(e^π) = π$. Then what is $ℓ(e^{3π}) =?$ Pls I need hint.
Here I started with: $ℓ(f(z))=g(z)$ iff $exp(f(z))=g(z)$. But I am confused on how I can  set $f & g $ here.

Comment: If $L$ is a branch of the logarithm, you must have $e^{L(z)} = z$, so you must exclude $0$. That is, you cannot define a branch of the logarithm on $D$.

Comment: Ohh I see...Thanks!

Comment: Should the domain be $D-\{1\}$ instead?

Answer (score 1):

A few notes about a branch of the logarithm  first:

A branch of the logarithm is a continuous function $L$ defined on a simply connected domain $D$ such that $e^{L(z)} = z$ for all $z$.

Since $e^z \neq 0$ for all $ z$ we cannot have $0 \in D$.

We have that $e^z = e^w$ **iff** $z=w+2\pi n i$ for some $n$.

If $L_1,L_2$ are two branches of the logarithm defined on $D$, then
we must have $L_1(z) = L_2(z) + 2 \pi n_z i$, and since $L_k$ are continuous,
we must have $L_1(z) = L_2(z) + 2 \pi n i$ for some **fixed** $n$ and for
all $z \in D$.

Now for the specific $D$ in the question, we see that $0 \in D$, so this cannot be the domain of a branch of the logarithm.

However, if you let $D = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ e^{(1+i)t} -1 \}_{t \ge 0}$ instead,
you can define a branch of the logarithm on $D$. Note that
$(0,e^{2 \pi}) \subset D$.

Let $D' = (1,e^\pi+1) \times (-1,1) \subset D$, and note that $D'$ is a simply
connected domain. The principal branch of the logarithm, $\log$ is defined
here, hence we know that
$L(z) = \log z +n$ for some $n$ and $z \in D'$.

Since $L(e^\pi) = \pi$, we see that $n=0$ and so $\log = L$ on $D'$.

Let $P = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ t \}_{t \le 0}$ be the domain on which $\log$ is defined.

A little work shows that the path
$e^\pi \to e^\pi+20i \to -100 + 20i \to -100 - 300 i \to e^{3 \pi} - 300 i \to e^{3 \pi}$ is contained in $D$, and that this path crosses $P$
once at $-100$.

We know that $L=\log$ for the first portion of the path and that $L$ is
continuous at $-100$, so we see that for the portion of the path
after $-100$, we have $L(z) = \log z + 2\pi i$. The remainder of the
path lies in $D \cap P$, hence we see that
$L(e^{3 \pi}) = \log (e^{3 \pi})+ 2\pi i = 3 \pi +2 \pi i$.

Comment: @coppe.hat...Thanks for your detail. But If $L(e^\pi) = \pi$, then why not $e^{L(e^{3\pi})}=e^{3\pi}$ implies $L(e^{3\pi})=3\pi ?$.... I am still confused here

Comment: @UserAb: That works with $\log$, the principal branch, but not with $L$. Even with $\log$, it is not true that $ \log(z_1 z_2) = \log z_1 + \log z_2$ in general.

Comment: For example, with $z_1 = i, z_2 = i$, we see that $\log (z_1 z_2)$ is not even defined in the principle branch.